# Triggering the 3cx call button of the 3cx-clicktotalk WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, 3cx

I am trying to find a way to remotely trigger the 3cx-clicktotalk call button remotely so I can use a custom button.

I have tried calling the button with jquery remote triggers but I am having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a Middleware Software which will trigger calls. You can initiate this via HTTP requests. 
Look for 3cX Call Control APIs to get started.

Answer (score -1):

This should be like this.

You can use only "WordPress/Website Integration" features from 3CX Settings.